# Wordpress get the current permalink/canonical URL?

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook, woocommerce

I need to insert the my page permalink on the end of a Facebook share URL.

Any help is much appreciated. E.g. `<a href="facebook.com/share.php/'<?php the_permalink(); ?>'">` doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

The format of the Facebook sharing link is:

```
https://www.facebook.com/share.php?u={{LINK}}
```

So in your example it'd be:

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
```